# Помощь с маршрутизацией по вложенным папкам

Tags: php, laravel, ui, auth

Доброе время, я пишу на Laravel простой сайт с регистрацией для 3 пользователей. Всё работает. Регистрация проходит в нужные таблицы. А вот после авторизации постоянно кидает пользователя в корень ресурсов и ищет вьюшку. Если её перемещаю в подпапку и прописываю её путь, то вообще пишет мол контроллер не найден, либо 404 ошибка.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где копать? В роутах или контроллы?
Могу прислать весь проект.

Comment: Если у вас к роуту идет контроллер, то смотрите путь в рендере контроллера. В другом случае в роуте

Comment: Понял. Самое смешное, что все работает, кроме выхода (логаут ссылается на папку аутч, которая удалена)

Comment: кеш мб..не делали route cache ?

Comment: Да конечно делал